# IQueryable: add matching-xquery condition

Tags: c#, linq, xquery, expression-trees

IQueryable allows developers construct query and then evaluate it.

Is there any way to add a condition that object's xml field matches xquery?

If I have preloaded query, I would just do this:

```
        var x = from acc in DB.account select acc;
        x = x.Where(acc => acc.info.XPathSelectElement("//LastName").Value == "admin");
```

But, if I have linq-to-sql or NHibernate, is this possible?

Comment: What SQL would you expect that query to generate?

Comment: I'm guessing `SELECT * FROM account WHERE account.info.value('//LastName', varchar(max)) = 'admin'`

Comment: yeah. sql query, using `.value(<xpath>)`. Is that passible from linq?